# Searching Across Django Models against Search Form Query

Tags: python, django, forms

I've been reading up on Django forms and am stumped on how to proceed. I'm creating a forms.py with the aim that at the form level, a user can input a string query, and this query is then run against one of the models, depending on which one is selected from a drop-down on the form. Something like the following in HTML:

```
<div class="row">
<form class="col s12">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s6" >
      <input type="text" class="validate" list="option">
    </div>
```

```
  <option value="1">model 1</option>
  <option value="2">model 2</option>
  <option value="3">model 3</option>
</select>
```

So essentially the query should be run against the appropriate model in views.py. Each model has its own view function. Also, how should I structure my urlconf to account for this?

Comment: can you post what you have in your `forms.py`?

Answer (score 0):

I would do this by doing something like this in the view:

```
class MySearchView(View):
    template_name = 'my_app/my_template.html'
    model_dict = {'1':MyFirstModelClass, '2': MySecondModelClass, '3': MyThirdModelClass}
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwags):
        my_search_form = MySearchFormClass(request.GET)
        if form.is_valid():
            model_class_to_search = model_dict[form.cleaned_data['name_of_model_form_field']]
            #run query here on model_class_to_search
            model_class_to_search.objects.filter(field1=form.cleaned_data['name_of_form_search_field'])
```